# Links shortener with advanced reporting?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, links, web-services

I am searching for a script (preferably in PHP) or an external solution which lets me create an "URL shortener" with advanced reports.

We have been using [Google Short Links](https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=5143210%206352879591152674960&pli=1) for a while: it works really well, but it lacks reporting (it only displays a counter with the total number of redirects). Our setup is as follows: "go.mydomain.com" points to the web service, and we can create links such as "go.mydomain.com/product1".

What I'm looking for is a similar service (or self-hosted solution) but with advanced reports, so we can track redirects by day, month, etc, distinguish between mobile and desktop users (very important!) and so on.

Comment: @Su': was it really necessary to edit my question to remove the "thanks" at the end? -.-"

Comment: Yes, that is generally not accepted here.

Comment: @Qualcuno I can't find the reference link right this second, but the short version is that the SE sites aren't really for "discussion" per se. (See also: if there are more than five comments on a response, the system starts suggesting you take it to chat.) Just establish the facts and ask your question, without all the hello please and thanks. Those niceties pretty much just take up space and are discouraged. All that said, if you want to continue discussing this, [it probably belongs in meta](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:
http://briancray.com/2009/08/26/free-php-url-shortener-script/
and this:
http://yourls.org/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However: the first one doesn't have any reporting (a part from a basic counter). The second one doesn't track links from desktop/mobile...
Do you know any hosted solutions, by the way?

Answer (score 4):

[Bitly Enterprise](http://www.bitlyenterprise.com/) will probably cover anything you need, but it's ~$1000/mo flat, no cheaper plans. The stats included with free bitly accounts(previously part of bitly Pro) are pretty minimal.

Comment: That's too much expensive... I don't mind paying, but 995$/month is really too much.

Comment: I suspected it might be, but it's the only one I know of that really offers any significant reporting. Don't know why most/all the other options seem uninterested in filling the massive price gap from free to this.

Comment: Thanks. I think we will just write a script by ourselves, as soon as we have some time. And maybe release it publicly on github after, given the current available options...